# creating a new column to indicate variable number of each unique animal

Tags: r, variables, numbers

I need to change the format of my current data by creating a new column as "tnum"(first column)to indicate trait/variable numbers and the last column "tval" to indicate each trait value. 
My current data file (9,000 animals) is similar to this format:

```
anim <- c(201,202,203,204,205) 
bwt <- c(1.2,1.0,0.9,1.1,1.5)
leng <- c(14,21,18,16,19)
temp <- c(33,34,39,38,37) 
mydf <- data.frame(anim,bwt,leng,temp)

   anim bwt  leng  temp
1  201  1.2   14   33
2  202  1.0   21   34
3  203  0.9   18   39
4  204  1.1   16   38
5  205  1.5   19   37
```

Trait 1 = bwt, trait 2 = leng, and trait 3 = temp. This what I am looking for:

```
tnum    anim   tval
 1      201    1.2
 2      201    14
 3      201    33
 1      202    1.0
 2      202    21
 3      202    34
 1      203    0.9
 2      203    18
 3      203    39
 1      204    1.1
 2      204    16
 3      204    38
 1      205    1.5
 2      205    19
 3      205    37
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Baz

Comment: @Ben Bolker: I always have problems with formating my question, that is, everything is running from left to right, especially when it comes to data frames where I want to have distinguished rows and columns. I was trying to do the same with the above question (as was raised by Ido Tamar) but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library("reshape")
m <- melt(mydf, id.vars="anim")
m
   anim variable value
1   201      bwt   1.2
2   202      bwt   1.0
3   203      bwt   0.9
4   204      bwt   1.1
5   205      bwt   1.5
6   201     leng  14.0
7   202     leng  21.0
8   203     leng  18.0
9   204     leng  16.0
10  205     leng  19.0
11  201     temp  33.0
12  202     temp  34.0
13  203     temp  39.0
14  204     temp  38.0
15  205     temp  37.0
```

and please format your code better next time. its simple.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance and I apologise for the format. However, I would prefer "variable" to have 1, 2, 3 instead of bwt, leng, and temp.

Comment: @ Ido Tamir:                                                                        This is what I need:                                                               tnum anim  tval
1     201  1.2
2     201  14
3     201  33
1     202  1.0
2     202  21
3     202  34
1     203  0.9
2     203  18
3     203  39
1     204  1.1
2     204  16
3     204  38
1     205  1.5
2     205  19
3     205  37

Comment: ms <- m; ms$variable <- as.numeric(m$variable). I would however advise to stay with labeled variables as long as possible, since it makes errors less  likely.

Comment: @baz: take the results of this question and use `m$tnum <- as.numeric(m$variable)` (and reorder/rename the columns if you like). More precisely: `m2 <- with(m,data.frame(tnum=as.numeric(variable), anim=anim,tval=value))`.  I agree with Ido's comment about staying with labeled variables.

Comment: @Ido Tamir;@Ben Bolker: thanks a lot for your help. I will stay with the variable codes instead of numbers.